# Is there a way to force NVCC to use the newer version of cl?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

Upgrading Visual Studio bumped up the cl version which made it unsupported by NVCC and now I can't compile. I tried updating to the latest Cuda version, but that did not work either. Can NVCC be forced to behave here?

Comment: No it can't. Don't upgrade VS if you are using 2017.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, installing the old version is nowhere near as heavy as the installer made it seem. It said it would be 3.7gb, but it finished downloading in 5m on my slow connection, so it must be a trifle. This solves my problem.